# tcpdump voip terminator ip address

Tags: linux, tcp, voip

I want to know how tcpdump can be used to find the end ip address in the call transport that actually terminates the call

[caller]---->[asterisk]---->[carrier]---->[call terminator]

As the call flow above indicates it shows a call is made into asterisk which sends it to a carrier. I want to see where the call is sent after this. What options can I use in tcpdump that will show  the ip address of the call terminator?

Answer (score 0):

Depending of what the carrier does you would not be able to know, which is actually the most common case.

The carrier may act as a Back-To-Back-User-Agent (B2BUA). This means that it will generate an outbound call to a terminator for every call you make, and bridge them back to back internally. Thus, you never get to see the terminator.

Carriers usually use SBCs (Session Border Controllers) for this.